# I am getting Attribute error for "append" in pandas even for "concat"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For below code, I get an attribute error,

```
total_device_df = total_device_df.append(KatsRequest().parse_json_response(filename, device_names))
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?

While I googled, it taught I need to update from `total_device_df.append ---> total_device_df.concat` as I am using Pandas Version: 2.0.1. Even though I changed to concat, I get the same attribute error for concat (`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `concat` is not deprecated. Make sure to restart your notebook/script/shell and to ensure you have not modified the DataFrame object. If you doubles checked, please provide your python and pandas version and a **fully reproducible** example (imports/data/code)

Comment: `concat` isn't a dataframe function, it's a pandas function. By that I mean it's `pd.concat` instead of `total_device_df.concat`. Try doing `pd.concat([total_device_df, KatsRequest().parse_json_response(filename, device_names)])`

Comment: result_df = result_df.append(
                            {'DEVICE': Trona, 'POOL': somepoolname, 'DSN': 123x,
                             'STATUS': online, 'LAST UPDATED': updated,
                             'RUNNING TIME': 1, 'CONNECTED HOST': somehostname,
                             'HW_CONFIG': yes, 'USER': username}, ignore_index=True)

print(result_df)

The above throws,
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?

@mozway

Comment: Also since it is a Dictionary, I cant use append.